# Implicit array using sumif in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, nested, statistics

I'd like to know if it's possible to use the SUMIF function with implicit or "nested" arrays. With "implicit" array I mean a matrix which data isn't in it's final form in any rank of the spreadsheet, but it's function of some other array. For example, lets say that we have data of an independent variable (which values, all integers, range from 0 to 5) in the rank A1:A100, and data of a dependent variable in B1:B100. With the SUMIF function we may calculate easily, for example, the sum of the dependent variable when the independent is 4. But if we want to know the sum of the SQUARES of the dependent variable it's not that easy, indeed, the SUMIF function gives an error if we write SUMIF(A1:A100;4;B1:B100^2) no matter how we enter it (as array or as a simple formula).

Is there any way to do this without having to waste an entire column for the squares of the values of column B?

I know that for this very example the function SUMPRODUCT((A1:A100=4)*B1:B100^2) would do the job, what I don't know is how to "nest" arrays (which is very useful) in general.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, I'm afraid. The ranges used in `COUNTIF(S)`/`SUMIF(S)`/`AVERAGEIF(S)` **must** be either:

1) References to worksheet ranges

2) Constructions which resolve to references to worksheet ranges

One example of the former:

`=SUMIF(A1:A10,"A",B1:B10)`

And two of the latter (which just happen to be identical to the above):

`=SUMIF(A1:INDEX(A:A,10),"A",B1:INDEX(B:B,10))`

`=SUM(SUMIF(OFFSET(A1,{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},),"A",OFFSET(B1,{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},)))`

Here `SUMPRODUCT` has the advantage over this group of functions, in that constructions may be passed which do not necessarily resolve to worksheet ranges.

However, it might well be the case that a more efficient set-up is achieved by, as you suggested,  first using an additional column within the worksheet to compute the squares and then referencing that column within a `SUMIF`, not least since one of the major advantages that `COUNTIF(S)`, `SUMIF(s)`, etc. can claim over `SUMPRODUCT` is that arbitrarly large references can be passed with no detriment to calculation performance. For example, the difference in performance between:

`=SUMIF(A:A,"A",B:B)`

and:

`=SUMPRODUCT(0+(A:A="A"),B:B)`

is enormous, the latter, having to process all 1,048,576 cells within that range (whether they are technically beyond the last-used cells or not), being not at all recommendable.

Regards